# Write python file with various asci codes

Tags: python

I would like to write a python file containing four bytes:

- A space
- A tab
- A carriage return
- A newline

I'm not able to write it as:

```
open('file.txt', 'w').write(' \t\r\n')
```

As for whatever reason it's converting the `\r` into a `\n`. How would I then write this as the asci codes themselves? that is:

```
NEWLINE = 10
CARRIAGE = 13
SPACE = 32
TAB = 9
open('file.txt','wb').write(bytearray([SPACE, TAB, CARRIAGE, NEWLINE]))
```

Comment: Your first example doesn't use binary mode (note `'w'` instead of `'wb'`), and converting newlines is *literally* the entire difference between binary and text mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the file in binary mode and write a byte string.

```
open('file.txt', 'wb').write(b' \t\r\n')
```